# What is some book that is complete and easy but hard enough to serve as prerequisite for asset pricing and portfolio choice theory?

Tags: asset-pricing, financial-engineering

What is some book that is complete and easy but hard enough to serve as prerequisite for asset pricing and portfolio choice theory by kerry back?

I wonder how come a beginning graduate textbook is so hard...

Comment: Introduction to Mathematical Portfolio Theory  -- by Joshi and Paterson is at a lower level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend "Active Portfolio Management" from Richard Grinold and Ronald Kahn. The book builds up most theories used in portfolio composition with much detail.